# .NET Core Identity. Use one context or two?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity

I am struggling with a basic problem. Keep my ASP.NET Core Identity context separate from my business context or combine the two.

Philosophically, it seems good to keep them separate. If I want to upgrade .NET Core at some point in the future, I have fewer issues if my identity context is separate.

Practically, it seems like a good idea to combine them. Otherwise, I am creating another user table or doing some weird workarounds to get user information from navigation properties.

How do you handle Identity contexts in .NET Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, its a good idea to keep identity context, separate from your business logic.

- You will probably have to do some expensive encryption and other things on your identity database. There may be no need to apply such encryption to your business data
- You might choose to replace, have separate backup plans and recovery plans for your identity database. non-identity database may have its own plan.
- More importantly, one fine day, you might decide and go with a 3rd party auth provider and forget about managing identity yourself. At which point, you may do some migration, throw away the identity database as it is no longer needed.

So, yes, best to use different context/database.

note : I am assuming, each context is linked to a different database. This is a given, but, for the sake of clarity, putting it here.

Comment: So, following up on part of my question. Would you then create a different user table in the other database? So the authentication database contains the minimum for authenticating a user and the "main" database would have user facing information about the user like name, etc?

Comment: The user database will have everything related to user, name and everything related to the user like roles, password recovery and so on. Anything that needs to be secured and perhaps encrypted at some point.

Comment: Then how does one join from this table to tables in the other database? If I have several tables in the main database that need a user id field how does one accomplish that in the split database scenario?

Comment: if you have new questions, you should consider posting a new question :) comments are meant for additional clarification. Post a new question, and you can link that to this.

Comment: If you read my original question, I bring up the point . Unfortunately just saying "I use two contexts" really doesn't answer what I asked. Perhaps my wording wasn't clear enough if others are seeing it differently.

Comment: @AbrahamLincoln then, we can keep it here. my bad. going through your stuff. i usually use the flat database method. two dbs - USERDB & CONTENTDB. Each user will have a unique ID, say, email address. everything related to the user, that gets stored in CONTENTDB, will have this unique id. So, when you login, you get the user id from the USERDB, and then, match it up with the user records on the CONTENTDB. Again, this is one strategy that I have used in project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222244/discussion-between-jay-and-abraham-lincoln).