# ASP.NET Core Identity table AspNetUsers

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

So, I am using ASP.NET Core Identity for the first time. I want to have one context for my login. I want another context for business objects. Where I am struggling is if I do this, I have the problem of users. I cannot use navigation properties to join business objects with a user under this strategy.

Initial thoughts are that I am going to have a user table separate from the `AspNetUsers` table in order to be able to do these joins. This means that somehow in my business logic, I need to populate this User table on creation of a record in `AspNetUsers`.

How have others handled this? Am I on the wrong track altogether here? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: could you try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64083720/net-core-identity-use-one-context-or-two . there was a similar situation, if not identical. there are a ton of comments as well.

Comment: this is how I always setup almost all of projects, so this is nothing new. its fairly routine, what you are trying to attempt. I think, almost all projects are build this way and its nothing specific to .NET core or even .NET.

Comment: `This means that somehow in my business logic, I need to populate this User table on creation of a record in AspNetUsers.`Yes,you need to hanldle the relationship with business code,so you can also use only [one dbcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807810/mvc5-identity-multiple-context-in-entityframework),so that it will be easier to handle the relationship.

Comment: Yes, Jay, I know as it was my question...

Comment: I considered using one context, Yiyi You. But then that makes it much more difficult to switch providers if I ever choose to,